# How can I set top and bottom margins to ZERO in Scrivenings mode between documents?

Tags: scrivener

Is it possible to set top and bottom margins to ZERO in Scrivenings mode so that I do not have big spaces between documents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Preferences > Formatting, under the *Scrivenings* subsection, there's a checkbox called "Separate Scrivenings with single line breaks."

On macOS, enabling that option reduces the distance between scrivenings to a single empty line. Folders are marked with a left margin bracket and an empty line.